# How can modify upload file name in custom function wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have custom upload function that upload files in my WordPress.

My custom template upload_page.php

```
if ( isset($_FILES['test_upload']) ) {
$a = $_FILES['test_upload'];
$arr = array();

foreach ($_FILES['test_upload'] as $key => $value) {

    foreach ($value as $k => $v) {

        $arr[$k][$key] = $a[$key][$k];

    }
}
foreach ($arr as $key => $file) {
    upload_user_file($file);
}
}
```

This my html form to upload files:

```
<form id="" class="" action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="test_upload[]" id="test_upload" accept=".pdf" multiple />
    <input onclick="move()" type="submit" />
</form>
```

And this my functions:

```
        if(isset($file_return['error']) || isset($file_return['upload_error_handler'])){
            return false;
        }else{
      $filename = $file_return['file'];
            $attachment = array(
                'post_mime_type' => $file_return['type'],
                'post_content' => '',
                'post_type' => 'attachment',
                'post_status' => 'inherit',
                'guid' => $file_return['url']
            );
```

I need put in name of upload file the user name that have upload it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your function '**upload_user_file**' :

**EDIT**

```
$user = wp_get_current_user();
$username = $user->user_login;
$filename = $file_return['file'] . $username;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Paul but your code give an error: Catchable fatal error: Object of class WP_User could not be converted to string in

Comment: Ok i think that wp_get_current_user() is array i resolve with $filename = $file_return['file'] . $current_user->user_lastname;

Comment: This correct but output is: filename.xxxSTRING, how can i have STRINGfilename.xxx, i try but commit some error.

Comment: $filename = $username . $file_return['file'];

Comment: Past your function code in a jsfiddle or something else please

Comment: It's just for the indentation :)

Comment: Thanks, it must work with your code. Be sure to have update your file correctly on your server and clear your browser cache. In which case I do not know what happens :(

Answer (score 0):

```
$current_user = wp_get_current_user();

$filename = $file_return['file'] . "_" .$current_user->display_name;
```

"$current_user->display_name" you can get current user name like this.

[to get current user name](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_current_user)

hope this will work for you.

Comment: This correct but output: filename.xxxSTRING, how can i have STRINGfilename.xxx, i try but commit some error.